# Python: looping code to substitute values from a list into variables in code

Tags: python, loops, variables, substitution

Let's say I have the following code below:

```
df_HA_noHA_append_5_X = df_HA_noHA_append_5[df_HA_noHA_append_5['Region'] == 'Y']
```

I want X to be different values from a list. For example I want `X` to be substituted in by:

```
df_list = [Central, West, East, South].
```

I also want Y to be different values from a separate list.  For example I want `Y` to be substitued in by:

```
df_list_2 = [M1, M2, M3, M4].
```

I have no clue how to write looping code for this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you wish the variable name to be dynamic, then use that name as the key in a dictionary.  For iterating through a list, use a `for` loop https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: There are mutliple ways to tackle the issue. You could use ``replace``, ``translate`` or ``string.Template``. Please show us what you've tried so far and where you got stuck.